# Add some words before counters of enumerate environment in beamer

Tags: beamer, indentation, enumerate

I want to change the default style of enumerate from

1. item1
2. item2

to

Stage 1. item1

Stage 2. item2

So I use

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{Stage \arabic{enumi}.}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\arabic{enumi}.}
```

But I find that the position of the counter (enumi) is fixed while the word "Stage" is pushed to the left border of the slide (See the snapshot below).

[image]

So what can I do to have the enumerate counter display normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not optimal, the following is a temporary work-around (until someone else provides a better alternative):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@enum@}{\llap}{\mbox}{}{}% \llap -> \mbox in \beamer@enum@
\makeatother
...
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{~~Stage \arabic{enumi}.}
```

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) uses a left overlap (`\llap`) for item labels in the `enumerate` environment. Hence, making this an `\mbox` (using `\patchcmd` from the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) plus adding `~~` to the `enumerate item` as a prefix provides the correct spacing.